# #VALUE from IF AND CONCATENATE formula in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, concatenation

Anyone have thoughts on why this won't work? I keep getting `#VALUE`.

```
=IF(E22:K22<>"", CONCATENATE(E22, " ", "of", " ", G22, " ", "with", " ", K22, " ", "from", " ", I22), "")
```

Comment: I think it is the E22:K22 <> "" part. What happens if you remove the concatenate formula and replace it with "1", do you get the 1 then? If not, try using ISEMPTY() to test the emptyness of cells

Answer (score 0):

If you want to ensure that the cells E22 to K22 have content and only execute the concatenation if all cells have content, then you can use a check like this:

```
=IF(COUNTA(E22:K22)=7, CONCATENATE(E22, " ", "of", " ", G22, " ", "with", " ", K22, " ", "from", " ", I22),"")
```

Comment: If that solved your problem, please mark it as the answer as explained in the [tour]. That's how you can say "thanks" here.

Answer (score 0):

You should use ; character instead of , character in the formula.

In the logical test of the IF you can use one of the count function on the interval E22:K22 to assure some or each of the cells have a value, as suggeste in teylyn answer.

As alternative in the logical test you can use AND to test each distinct cell for being not empty - or for having a specific value - in example
=IF(AND((E22<>"");(F22<>"");(G22<>"");(K22<>"") ); CONCATENATE(E22; " "; "of";" "; G22;" ";"with"; " "; K22; " "; "from"; " ";I22); "")
will check if E, F, G, and K are not empty, but omit checking H, I, J cells.
In this way (if you need the furmula to be more flexible) you can customize the check for each cell.

Comment: Whether to use `comma` or `semicolon` in the formula depends on the Windows Regional Settings of the host computer.  And if you use the wrong one, you get a `there is an error with this formula` message.  Absent that message, what makes you recommend that?

Comment: The "this won't work" part fooled me, I should have read better the op was getting #VALUE rather than an error message.